# Python: direct requesting with requests.get('http.weatherdataexample.com/example.json')

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I'm using **Python 3.x** and the lib **requests**.
is there a way to get a specific value by putting the whole path from a json-file without downloading first the whole json?

I have the follow code to get weatherdata:

```
import requests

data=requests.get('http.weatherdata.com/example.json')
current_wind=a.json()['features'][48]['properties']['value']
```

is there a way to request directly the "current wind" like somehow like the following? this could decrease traffic from the request.

```
import requests

current_wind=requests.get('http.weatherdata.com/example.json',['features'][48]['properties']['value'])
```

i was looking for that specific question for quite a while... almost gave up.
thank for your answer.

Comment: This is not a Python question but a question about the API of weather data.  If it is possible (I do not know that API), you will be able to prepare que adequate request with Pyhon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be more accurate in the question and/or give examples.

But I think you mean something like this:

```
a=requests.get('http.weatherdata.com/example.json')
current_wind=a.json()['features'][48]['properties']['value']
```

You have to define the variable for the request, then convert it into json.

Comment: sorry for my unaccurate question.      i mean your code, but there. It downloads first the whole example.json and after then looking for the specific value. Is there a way to parse directly and only the specific value without get the whole example.json file first?

Comment: I don't think so :( . Why don't you want to load the whole file? Is it because of speed of the reuqets module?

Comment: :( so i have to live with that. its more about traffic of usless data :)   thank you!